# Pondering FileUriExposedException in Android 7

Tags: android

I'm an Android developer, and got a Nougat device recently, and noticed that a lot of the apps I've written crash on this device.

The crashes are traceable to FileUriExposedException, and I'm aware of the cause and fixes for this (targetSdkVersion < 24, FileProvider, content URIs, VmPolicy with StrictMode, etc.)

But I'm less clear on the big picture here.  In my case, I have about a dozen apps that are interconnected, and they pass file URIs to each other.  I can change them to the new standard, but doing so doesn't benefit me, and I also make use of old apps that I have no control over, and that don't know anything about content URIs.

I tried several file managers that I have, and noticed that an old version of ES File Explorer, and a new version of Mixplorer, both use file URIs when invoking apps, whereas Solid Explorer is using content URIs.  So the situation appears to be very much up in the air.

I'm familiar with the Linux world, where it's possible to have either tight or loose file permissions.  It's clear to me what the tight equivalent is on Nougat, but is there any equivalent of loose permissions?  At the moment, my thought is to turn off the exception using the two-line StrictMode scheme, while gradually tweaking my applications in the desired direction, for example by handling both file and content URIs that are passed in.

Does anyone have thoughts on the bigger picture here?

Comment: If you put the target sdk version a bit lower than all works in the old way. Or am i wrong by that?

Comment: `have about a dozen apps that are interconnected, and they pass file URIs to each other. `. Dont pass an uri then. Pass uri.toString,().

Comment: Using StrictMode is dirty programming.